# Auto Incrementing numbers and letters

Tags: vb.net

I have a textboxt with alpha numeric numbers - 001 ,002, 003, numbers.text, and a second textbox called suffix.text. How would I be able to auto increment the suffix, so if the user enters 001 as first entry in the numbers.text and then the next value they add is also 001, I need the suffix.text to automatically show this.

So it would look like this:

```
number.text     suffix.text
001
001                 a
001                 b
002 
002                 a
```

Etc.

Comment: Which part of this task are you having trouble with?

Comment: What do you want to happen if/when there are more than 27 of '001' - which would be 'z'?